# move_uploaded_file not writing to server, nor returning anything

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, fwrite

I am trying to store a file, along with a few text fields, from an HTML form to my web server. The text is being written absolutely fine, however nothing is happening with the image. I have checked for errors, and none are showing up. The image is also being received in the email.
I believe the permissions are fine too - they are exactly the same on `/img/gallery/` and `/img/gallery/data/`.

Here is my PHP for the form:

```
<?php
include 'loadImages.php';
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];

/**
 * PHPMailer simple file upload and send example
 */
$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    // First handle the upload
    // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
    // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        // Upload handled successfully
        // Now create a message
        // This should be somewhere in your include_path
        require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->setFrom('gallery@####.co.uk', 'Website');
        $mail->addAddress('gallery@####.co.uk');
        $mail->Subject = 'Image Submission Recieved';
        $mail->msgHTML("<b>Name</b>: $name<br><b>Email</b>: $email<br><b>Location</b>: $location<br><b>Description</b>: $desc");
        // Attach the uploaded file
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'Image');
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $msg = "Your message has been sent.";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }

    $date = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/data/';
    $filename = $date.".txt";

    $file = fopen($path.$filename, "w") or die("Something went wrong storing your photo information");
      fwrite($file, $name . "\n");
      fwrite($file, $location . "\n");
      fwrite($file, $desc . "\n");
      fwrite($file, $email . "\n");
      fwrite($file, "Valid: False");
    fclose($file);

    $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/';
    $filename = $date . "." . pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $target = $path . $filename;
    echo $target;

    echo move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target);
}

$images = loadImages();
$imageData = LoadImageData();
?>
```

$_FILES:

```
1Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => hairy sun.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpWweCkX [error] => 0 [size] => 49526 ) )
```

If you need to see anything else, I will upload it.

Comment: What errors do you see in your error_log?

Comment: can you post the output of print_r($_FILES)?

Comment: @skrilled I am getting no errors at all.

Comment: @Jaime Updating it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shift this,

```
$date = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/data/';
$filename = $date.".txt";

$file = fopen($path.$filename, "w") or die("Something went wrong storing your photo information");
  fwrite($file, $name . "\n");
  fwrite($file, $location . "\n");
  fwrite($file, $desc . "\n");
  fwrite($file, $email . "\n");
  fwrite($file, "Valid: False");
fclose($file);

$name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/';
$filename = $date . "." . pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$target = $path . $filename;
echo $target;

echo move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target);
```

above this code,

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
```

Then try again.

Comment: I'm now getting `failed to move file to /temp/74ed5209e101d58611901d2b7d518cc11622a08e5HfbbE`

Comment: The image is actually being uploaded now, despite this error.

Comment: I believe this is because I am uploading it twice. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

You're saving it to your /tmp dir and I think it's getting cleaned up when the script exits. Try saving to another directory.

Comment: I changed line 18 to `$uploadfile = tempnam($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/temp/', sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));` but it still yeilds the same result. Is this what you meant?